# vba, userform show method

Tags: forms, vba, methods

Could someone explain me why way to show form and way to hide it are constructed differently.

Code to show form 
userform1.show

and code to hide it 
unload userform1.

why was not done userform1.unload?
why unload is written in front of userform?

thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use UserForm1.Hide to close it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UserForm` class has `Show` and `Hide` methods. With `Show` the form instance which lives in memory already will be displayed and with `Hide` it will be hidden. Hidden means the instance is still in memory and accessible but it is not visible.

---

In `VBA.Global` namespace there are mothods `Load` and `Unload`. With `Load` the object can be loaded into memory but is not visible and `Show` method needs to be called to display the form. With `Unload` the form is unloaded which removes it from memory and it is not accessible any more.

> So `Show/Hide` and `Load/Unload` are two different ways of working with a form.

IMO: the easiest approach is to create a variable of type e.g. `UserForm1` and then work with this variable. This variable holds a reference to the `UserForm1` and can be used to display or hide the form.

```
Dim frm1 As UserForm1 
Set frm1 = New UserForm1 ' Creates new instance in memory but does not display it yet
frm1.Show ' Displays the form
frm1.Hide ' Hides form but it remains in memory and is still accessible
set frm1 = Nothing ' Removes connection between variable frm1 and form instance.
' If no other references are available the form instance can be removed from memory
```